# Laravel failed to load resource, the resource serve r responded with a status of 404

Tags: laravel, alassetslibrary

I downloaded my laravel project from live serve (shared hosting) to local hosting because I want to make some changed in the code. I added a new index.php file to the public folder and run composer update and composer install commands and managed to run the project on local server (I use Laragon server on windwos). However, the project can not upload the resource. The resource are located in the public floder and linked using {{asset}} function and {{assetversion}} methods. Honestly, I do not know about the use of version. The code in like that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/frontend/infixlmstheme') }}/css/fontawesome.css{{assetVersion()}} ">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('public/backend/css/themify-icons.css')}}{{assetVersion()}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/frontend/infixlmstheme') }}/css/flaticon.css{{assetVersion()}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/frontend/infixlmstheme') }}/css/nice-select.css{{assetVersion()}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/frontend/infixlmstheme') }}/css/notification.css{{assetVersion()}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/frontend/infixlmstheme/css/mega_menu.css') }}">
```

When I check the path in chrom dev tools, the link points to the right folder (except the version in not in the file name). such as
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/frontend/infixlmstheme/css/fontawesome.css?v=5.0.0 ">`

and the folder in with same path starting from public.

However, the recourse is not connected and the error massage is shown in the attached image fro chrom dev tools.
[image]

I appreciate you help guys and thank you in advance for your time and expertise.

I have assempution the error is from {{assetversion}} but I could not find the version in the file name. I do not know a lot about the frontend how the asset version work.

Comment: can you please post the code from your project where some of these assets are being called? Also, it appears you are not loading jquery...throw in a jQuery link from a cdn somewhere and that will get rid of the `$ is not defined` errors

Comment: "*I added a new index.php file to the public folder*" - why did you do that?  What did you change?  Also, please check your question, none of your code is showing up, please edit and take some care with the formatting so we can see it.

Comment: Thank you maximus for your interest. The code now is shown in the question. I do not know what went wrong last time and the code had not been shown the question. I have not loaded jQuery and I am not sure whether it is used in the development or not. I am not the one who wrote the code but I am in charge of upgrading it.  Could you elaborate more on this point, please.

Comment: Thank you Don't Panic for your interest. Regarding the index.php file, for shared hosting the index file should be in the root folder or some modifications in the .htacess file are necessary to point the server to the public folder, which is the standard architecture in laravel. Laragon doe not serve the project without this modification.  I hope the code now is showing up. thank you again for you help.